# Pod install failed to fetch - fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I'm trying to pod install in my flutter project. This is the first time I'm running this project.
I use onesignal_flutter: ^3.5.1. When I pod install it failed to fetch the OneSignalXCFramework repo.

I get this error:

```
...
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.3.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.12.0)
Installing OneSignalXCFramework (3.12.4)

[!] Error installing OneSignalXCFramework
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK.git /var/folders/5f/bnc72_gj7430tsnm5bm42dsh0000gn/T/d20231208-56071-fzux4d --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 3.12.4

Cloning into '/var/folders/5f/bnc72_gj7430tsnm5bm42dsh0000gn/T/d20231208-56071-fzux4d'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 3182 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I tried changing global git configs. Didn't find any luck. I'm on macos sonoma. same issue with the latest onesignal_flutter plugin version.

git version - 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)

my usr/.gitconfig file

```
[user]
    name = shehan
    email = hello@gmail.com
[commit]
    template = .gitmessage
[http]
    postBuffer = 5242880000
    version = HTTP/1.1
[core]
    compression = 0
    packedGitLimit = 1024m 
    packedGitWindowSize = 1024m
[pack] 
    deltaCacheSize = 3096m 
    packSizeLimit = 3096m 
    windowMemory = 256m
```

Stuck with this for a whole day now.